# Указатель на char[] и string эквивалентны?

Tags: строки, c++, visual-c++

Функция WriteFile() в параметры принимает указатель на строку(мне нужно передать строку СТРОГО ТИПА ЧАР) и число байт, которые нужно передать с точки, куда "указал".

Инициализировать строку типа char крайне не удобно  в моем случае(в классе эти строки принимают всегда одно значение. не иниализировать же посимвольно!).

Вот и возникла потребность в Стринге. Он, кажется выделяет динамически char'ы, так что с типом параметра все ОК.

Но вот что меня волнует-т.к. память выделяется динамически, значит элементы в памяти идут не последовательно?! т.е. между элементами есть разрыв в памяти и тогда в моей передаче параметра будет логическая ошибка?!

Помогите разобраться, Пожалуйста:)

Comment: динамический массив (вектор) - хранит ячейки подрядят в памяти...

список (лист) - хранит указатель на следующею  ячейку...

стринг это basic_string<char> по сути вектор строк...


если я ошибаюсь и где то стринг хранится в виде списка то скажите где...

Comment: в stl есть реализация строк на базе списков (в стандарте ее нет, но к примеру в g++ есть). Называется rope. Оно нужно для очень больших строк, которые постоянно модифицируются.

Comment: @KoVadim огромное спасибо! очень интересная вещица!

нашел статью на [хабре][1], очень понравилась :)


  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/144736/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как содержатся символы внутри `std::string` -- внутреннее дело класса `std::string`, нас это не должно интересовать.

Однако у `std::string` есть функция `c_str()`, которая возвращает именно `char*` с последовательно расположенными символами. Она-то вам и нужна.

Answer (score 4):

Открываем стандарт и читаем

> The char-like objects in a `basic_string` object shall be stored contiguously. That is, for any `basic_string` object `s`, the identity `&*(s.begin() + n) == &*s.begin() + n` shall hold for all values of `n` such that `0 <= n < s.size()`.

пункт (21.4.1.5)

То есть, стандарт говорит, что класс, который реализует строку, должен выделять память непрерывным куском. По факту, большинство библиотек реализуют строку на базе вектора, для которого непрерывность гарантируется.

Но тип `std::string` имеет функцию c_str(), которая возвращает правильную c-строку (с нулем в конце). Длина строки также известна - функция `length()` или `size()` (эти функции - дубликаты, `length` создана исключительно для удобства). Правда завершающий ноль в эту длину не входит.

Но может быть и обычны с-строки хорошо заработают? Посмотрите на этот пример

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   char data[] = "test test";
   std::cout << data << " " << sizeof(data) << std::endl;
   // writeXXXX(data, sizeof(data));
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Строки сами по себе, действительно работают не плохо!
Но проблема с инициализацией в классе.  Мы же не можем инициализировать при объявлении.

Comment: можно инициализировать, если использовать последний стандарт и компиляторы. Но можно сделать и со старыми красиво

    #include <iostream>
    
    using namespace std;
    // этот namespace можно вынести в отдельный файл
    namespace my_str {
        string data = "test test";
        // здесь ещё много-много строк.
    }
    
    class Test {     
       public:
         void print() {
            cout << my_str::data << endl;
         }
    };
    
    int main() {
       Test t;
       t.print();
       
       return 0;
    }

Comment: Но всё же в C++ правильнее использовать строки. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/arrays-are-evil.html

Comment: опечатался. Но "ненормальный сдвиг"  на то и ненормальный:)